# Using geofencing for a specific longitude and latitude with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, geofencing

I'm making a real-time location tracking app, which means all users will push their positions (longitude and latitude) on a common Firebase database, and from there I can get them.

I (the current, main user) want to know when ANOTHER USER enters a specific area which I specify before. I've come across Geofencing, but because the only information I got from that user is its longitude and latitude, I can't find the way to make Geofencing work with a multiple-user system like this.

Comment: I think you may be looking at geo-queries, which you can run on top of the Firebase Realtime Database using GeoFire - an add-on library. See https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geofire?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `distanceTo` method to check if the users are within a specified radius.